# How to display linked images horizontally through html or css

Tags: html, css

for a sample website I'm trying to create, I'm trying to display a social medias horizontally instead of vertically... is there anyway I can do this through my code I have here?

I could include pictured files if you want me to, but I'm not sure how to do that through stack

```css
.fill-screen {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.make-it-fit {
    max-width: 99%;
    max-height: 99%;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

body {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

fieldset {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
}
legend {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 14em; 
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--bakhriddinov-->
<!-- -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Final Project</title>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        
        <!--font-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--significant element 1 DIV-->
     <div class='fill-screen' style = "overflow: auto; max-height: 100vh;">
            <h2><a id="top"></a></h2>
            <img src="takethejourney.png" alt="next"  height="70"/>
            
            <br>
            
        <!--significant element 2 IMAGES-->
            <a href="index2.html">
            <img src="savetheb.gif" alt="MAIN" height="400"/>
            </a>
            <br>
            <br>
            
        <!--significant element 4 LINKS TO OTHER INNER HTML-->
            <a href=""> 
            <img class='make-it-fit' 
         src=''>
            </a>   
            
            
        <!-- social medias -->    
            <p></p>
            
        <!--significant element 4 LINKS TO OTHER OUTER HTML-->
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/greenpeace.international?fref=ts">
                <img src="64x64facebook.png" alt="greenpeace's facebook" height="20" width="20"/>
            </a>    
            
            <p></p>  
            
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Greenpeace">
                <img src="64x64twitter.png" alt="greenpeace's twitter" height="20" width="20"/>
            </a>
            
            <p></p>
            
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/GreenpeaceVideo">
                <img src="64x64youtube.png" alt="greenpeace's youtube" height="20" width="20"/>
            </a>
            
            <p></p>
            
            <a href="http://www.greenpeace.org/">
                <img src="greenpeace_logo.png" alt="greenpeace" height="20"/>
            </a>
            
            <p></p>
   </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Check bootstrap grid , or grid in general , it's something like div class = col-xs-4 ....

Comment: just a tip. Next time you want to use images, try to use some placeholders, rather than the original code as they end up being invalid. Try https://placehold.it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get the images to display next to each other without changing too much is to simply wrap them in a container `<div>`. It doesn't even need any styling!

```css
.fill-screen {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.make-it-fit {
  max-width: 99%;
  max-height: 99%;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

fieldset {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
}

legend {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 85%;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
}

input,
select {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

input {
  width: 14em;
}

input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 1em;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--significant element 1 DIV-->
  <div class='fill-screen' style="overflow: auto; max-height: 100vh;">
    <h2>
      <a id="top"></a>
    </h2>
    <img src="takethejourney.png" alt="next" height="70" />

    <br>

    <!--significant element 2 IMAGES-->
    <a href="index2.html">
      <img src="savetheb.gif" alt="MAIN" height="400" />
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>

    <!--significant element 4 LINKS TO OTHER INNER HTML-->
    <a href="">
      <img class='make-it-fit' src=''>
    </a>


    <!-- social medias -->
    <div>

      <!--significant element 4 LINKS TO OTHER OUTER HTML-->
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/greenpeace.international?fref=ts">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="greenpeace's facebook" height="20" width="20" />
      </a>

      <a href="https://twitter.com/Greenpeace">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="greenpeace's twitter" height="20" width="20" />
      </a>

      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/GreenpeaceVideo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="greenpeace's youtube" height="20" width="20" />
      </a>

      <a href="http://www.greenpeace.org/">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="greenpeace" height="20" />
      </a>

    </div>
```

A div is a `block` element, so will occupy 100% of the width of the parent by default. Images are `inline-block`, so will attempt to display next to each other when inside of a `block` element.

Hope this helps! :)